# RoR: how to tell which params in a form have changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In a Rails application, I have a particular form with many fields for editing a resource.  Since I also want to log what was changed for this particular resource, I need to know which params changed.

Currently in this form, I have duplicated every field in the form with hidden field tags, so in the controller every field is compared to the corresponding hidden field to determine if the value was changed.  But it's a LOT of work in the view and in the controller.

Being relatively new to Rails, I'm finding all kinds of Rails "magic" as I go along, so I wonder: does the framework provide a way to do this for me?  Or is this pretty much the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveModel has exactly what you're looking for, take a look at the examples in the docs...

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

```
person = Person.find_by_name('Uncle Bob')
person.changed?       # => false
person.name = 'Bob'
person.changed?       # => true
person.name_changed?  # => true
person.name_was       # => 'Uncle Bob'
person.name_change    # => ['Uncle Bob', 'Bob']
person.name = 'Bill'
person.name_change    # => ['Uncle Bob', 'Bill']
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. In the rails 3 it was extracted to the ActiveModel. My link on the top is a little out of the date.

Comment: Thanks, Lloyd!  That looks perfect!  After all of the RTFM'ing I've done, I can't believe I never came across that before.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Dirty attributes for this task.

```
@post.attributes = params[:post]
@post.changed # or changes if you want to see what values on which was changed
```

More on that you can find by this link: http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Dirty.html

Also if you want to use versioning or auditing, try this gems (best ones are: paper_trail, acts_as_audited, vestal_versions):

- https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Versioning
- https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_User_Stamping

Comment: Don't forget in that case to add `attr_accessible` to be secured!